# Solr query on multivalued field

Tags: solr

I have a solr multivalue field like given in the example below.

```
<document>
    <id>1</id>
    <arr name="Keywords">
       <str>Market</str>
       <str>Test</str>
       <str>Test</str>
       <str>Global</str>
    </arr>
</document>
<document>
    <id>2</id>
    <arr name="Keywords">
       <str>Sales</str>
       <str>Global</str>
    </arr>
</document>
<document>
    <id>3</id>
    <arr name="Keywords">
       <str>Test</str>
    </arr>
</document>
```

So in the above example, I have three documents with a keywords array. I want to get all the documents where the keywords array has at least one different value other than **Test**. So query should return the first and the second document. It should not return the third document because keywords have only Test.